# Sorting strings doesn't work properly

Tags: c, sorting

I have rjecnik.txt file that looks like this

```
mate sime, jure
stipica gujo, prvi
ante mirkec
goran maja, majica
avion kuca, brod, seoce
amerika, neka, zemlja, krcma
brodarica, zgrada, zagreb
zagreb split
zadar rijeka
andaluzija azija
```

I need to order lines alphabetically (not words) and my program produces this result which is not correct:

```
andaluzija azijamate sime, jure
amerika, neka, zemlja, krcma
brodarica, zgrada, zagreb
ante mirkec
avion kuca, brod, seoce
goran maja, majica
stipica gujo, prvi
zadar rijeka
zagreb split
```

Press [Enter] to close the terminal ...
When I use non ascii character like kuća for kuca or krčma for krcma it produces this result (all wrong)

```
andaluzija azijamate sime, jure
amerika, neka, zemlja, krŔma
brodarica, zgrada, zagreb
ante mirkec
avion kuŠa, brod, seoce
goran maja, majica
stipica gujo, prvi
zadar rijeka
zagreb split
```

Press [Enter] to close the terminal ...
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int ch, nl = 1, min, lenght1, lenght2, lenght;//ch will hold characters, min is for selection sort, lenght holds value of strlen for determine wthat line is longer
    FILE * fp;// FILE pointer
    char * lines[1000];//that will dynamically hold strings for lines
    char * temp;//for lines swaping
    if((fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\don\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\proba2\\dist\\Debug\\MinGW-Windows\\rjecnik.txt", "r")) == NULL)//I had to temporarily put full path to rjecnik.txt
    {
        printf("Can't open file...");
        exit(1);
    }
    while((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)//count lines
    {
        if(ch == '\n')
            nl++;
    }
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < nl; i++)
        lines[i] = malloc(1000);//create array of string size value of nl
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);//go to start of file
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)//fill arrays of string
    {
        lines[i][j] = ch;
        j++;
        if(ch == '\n')
        {
           j = 0;
           i++;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < nl - 1; i++)//selection sort doesn't work properly
    {
        min = i;//min is i
        for(j = i + 1; j < nl; j++)//for number of lines(nl) times
        {
            lenght1 = strlen(lines[i]);//find what string is longer and lenght is smaller one
            lenght2 = strlen(lines[j]);
            if(lenght1 < lenght2)
                lenght = lenght1;
            else
                lenght = lenght2;
            if(strncmp(lines[i], lines[j], lenght) > 0 )//compare two strings
                 min = j;//if second string is alphabetically smaller min is j
        }
        temp = lines[i];// swapping
        lines[i] = lines[min];
        lines[min] = temp;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < nl; i++ )//printing to console
    {
        lenght1 = strlen(lines[i]);
        for(j = 0; j < lenght1; j++ )
        {
            putchar(lines[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now program crashes at the end when I add this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int ch, nl = 1, min, lenght1, lenght2, lenght;//ch will hold characters, min is for selection sort, lenght holds value of strlen for determine wthat line is longer
    FILE * fp;// FILE pointer
    char * lines[1000];//that will dynamically hold strings for lines
    char * temp;//for lines swaping
    if((fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\don\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\proba2\\dist\\Debug\\MinGW-Windows\\rjecnik.txt", "r")) == NULL)//I had to temporarily put full path to rjecnik.txt
    {
        printf("Can't open file...");
        exit(1);
    }
    while((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)//count lines
    {
        if(ch == '\n')
            nl++;
    }
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < nl; i++)
        lines[i] = malloc(1000);//create array of string size value of nl
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);//go to start of file
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)//fill arrays of string
    {
        lines[i][j] = ch;
        j++;
        if(ch == '\n')
        {
           j = 0;
           i++;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < nl - 1; i++)//selection sort doesn't work properly
    {
        min = i;//min is i
        for(j = i + 1; j < nl; j++)//for number of lines(nl) times
        {
            lenght1 = strlen(lines[i]);//find what string is longer and lenght is smaller one
            lenght2 = strlen(lines[j]);
            if(lenght1 < lenght2)
                lenght = lenght1;
            else
                lenght = lenght2;
            if(strncmp(lines[min], lines[j], lenght ) > 0 )//compare two strings
                 min = j;//if second string is alphabetically smaller min is j
        }
        temp = lines[i];// swapping
        lines[i] = lines[min];
        lines[min] = temp;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < nl; i++ )//printing to console
    {
        lenght1 = strlen(lines[i]);
        for(j = 0; j < lenght1; j++ )
        {
            putchar(lines[i][j]);
        }
    }
   for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)//Program crashes here
        free(lines[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.- You must initialize lines to 0 after malloc so strlen works properly.
2.- Compare lines[j] with lines[min]
3.- Don't forget free lines

Comment: Wait, when I want to free lines at the end of the program with for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        free(lines[i]); program crashes

Comment: You're only allocating for n1 lines, so you should only free those.

Comment: sorry I now I made mistake thinking about somting else

Answer (score 2):

You're always comparing lines[j] to lines[i], but you should be comparing it to lines[min].

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't you learning about how to sort and get input, c provides `qsort()` and `fgets()`, so you could

```
 int strsort(const void *a, const void *b)
 {
      char *const*astr=a, *const*bstr=b;
      return strcmp(*astr, *bstr);
 }

 main()
 {
     FILE*f = fopen(...);
     char (*arr)[1000] = malloc(1000*1000);
     int x;
     for(x=0;x<1000 && fgets(1000, arr[x], f);x++)
         arr[x][strlen(arr[x])-2] = '\0'; //strip newlines
     qsort(arr, x, 1, strsort);
     int i;
     for(i=0; i<x; i++)
          printf("%s\n", arr[x]);
 }
```

It's much clearer what you're doing this way.

Answer (score 0):

Minor nitpick:

```
lenght1 = strlen(lines[i]);
            lenght2 = strlen(lines[j]);
            if(lenght1 < lenght2)
                lenght = lenght1;
            else
                lenght = lenght2;
            if(strncmp(lines[i], lines[j], lenght) > 0 )
 ... ;
```

You don't need this: strcmp() stops when either of the strings terminates, whichever comes first. In your case, you need to compare one more character (the NUL), like

```
strncmp( lines[i], lines[j], lenght+1)
```

, otherwise "apple" and "apples" would compare equal (because only the first five characters would be compared). But the "normal" form:

```
strcmp(lines[i], lines[j])
```

does exactly what you want.